How can spotfire add a calculated column in data table with lookup function
I want to add a calculated column in my data table, but I can not find the function lookup function in expression function.



Layer ID
OVLTR
MT
Result




Cell A
NULL
MT_1



Cell B
Cell A
MT_2



Cell C
Cell A
MT_3



Cell D
Cell C
MT_4




Here is the example table,
as you can see Layer ID and OVLTR have identical cell value but in different row.
What I want to do is to find the matched Layer ID to OVLTR, and return MT of Layer ID.
Here is the result :



Layer ID
OVLTR
MT
Result




Cell A
NULL
MT_1



Cell B
Cell A
MT_2
MT_1


Cell C
Cell A
MT_3
MT_1


Cell D
Cell C
MT_4
MT_3



If you are familiar to excel, it is just a simple vlookup function, but I don’t know how to do it in spotfire?
I had done some search, some people say use and origin table and match the lookup table, this answer is no to me, because the origin table is 1GB excel and keep growing, it is difficult to me to use this method.
I also want to create custom expression function, but I don't know how, could someone please help me~~~~ no matter use the original function or custom function,
Thank You!!!!
